# Scrollbar is not hiding in Android chrome

Tags: html, css

I tried below options to hide scrollbar in my app

1. body::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
2. body::-webkit-scrollbar {width:0; background: transparent;}

Both the options are working fine in desktop but when I try in Android chrome, it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem in the past, and the way I solved it was replacing `overflow: scroll` with `overflow: auto;` which would still allow the div to be scrollable without showing the scroll bars.